# Read numeric text files using FREAD in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, fread, bcp

I'm aware that `fread` can be used for reading binary data.  I read somewhere that it can also read text files.  I have a numeric text file that I generated using `BCP` utility and SQL Server.  I am trying to read this huge data in Matlab.  `textscan` and `fscanf` are slow in my case.  `fread` reads the data and prints out their ASCII values.  Is there a way I can read the data correctly using `fread`?  Because text files are big, `fread` can give me a quicker solution.

BCP "SELECT 3,1 UNION ALL SELECT 9,13" queryout "Trial.txt" -c t"," -S"srvr" -U"login" -P"pwrd"

% In Matlab -->

```
    fid = fopen('Trial.txt','r') ;
    fread(fid)
    fclose(fid);
```

ASCII Output:

```
51                 % Ascii Char for 3 (http://www.asciitable.com/)
44                 % ...............,
49                 % ...............1
13                 % ...............carriage return
10
57
44
.......
```

Comment: `fileread` should do well too. It's basically a simple `fread` call... If you check `doc fread` you'll see that fread supports lots of conversion options.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Just use `char` after `fread` to interpret the read bytes as ASCII characters. Also add `.'` if you want a row vector instead of a column vector:

```matlab
fid = fopen('Trial.txt','r');
chars = char(fread(fid)).';
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: -> Thanks. Any str2num conversion hangs my PC.  This is not a workable solution when using big files.